# VPN console dongle

Tags: vpn, ethernet-port

For some reason the only way to connect a console or a streaming device to a VPN is thought a windows PC by sharing the network.

My idea is to make a dongle of sorts were I can connect an ethernet cable from my router to a raspberry pi (zero preferably) and output another ethernet cable with VPN connection to my console.

I was wondering if it possible first to add to two ethernet ports to a raspberry pi zero or to use another hardware more suited for the task. Second to connect the raspberry pi to a VPN (let's say NordVPN) through the first ethernet port. And third to share that VPN connection to the second ethernet port

Pd: could also be possible to simultaneously add pihole to filter out ads to the previous idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Ethernet ports, but you will also need a USB hub.

Frankly, by the time you have done this it would be cheaper (an neater) to buy a Pi with Ethernet and USB ports.

Comment: But there is a way to connect to ethernet modules, but without using a USB hub?

Comment: There are Ethernet modules which connect via SPI, but the better option is still a Pi B